# Laravel 5 database.sqlite can't connect

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, phpstorm

If I connect to the service with a browser the service and the database is working but I'm not able to connect to the file through the database tab in PhpStorm.

[image: Database-Connection]

#### config/database.php:

```
'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

#### .env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:CYcuLxJOaQGcxX70vKQrkrdBUc2V5mgVzBMzF8m0h/A=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
#DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
#DB_PORT=3306
#DB_DATABASE=homestead
#DB_USERNAME=homestead
#DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Comment: Try avoiding `database_path` in the config. It's possible that's not getting defined when the config gets loaded

Comment: @apokryfo didn´t work, the database is working normally, because if I go in the browser and use the web-service I get no error and the db is working

Comment: Sorry. I just spotted PhpStorm part

Comment: Must be something wrong with JDBC driver that PhpStorm is using to connect to SQLite database -- the error on screenshot suggests just that. Try re-downloading drivers.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Check your .env files**

You should uncomment this part, remove "#" sign and make sure your credential into database is correct.

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1  
DB_PORT=3306   
DB_DATABASE=homestead  
DB_USERNAME=homestead  
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Comment: @pache. There's some error warning in your IDE. Can you showing your log error in your post or put into pastebin? We need specific information for this issue